# 'Show apps' not displaying installed apps

Tags: snap

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 23.10.  I have installed a few programs but they are not showing up in 'Show apps'.  I have seen many posts covering this type of issue but nothing has solved my issue.

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: More details will help you get the answer you need. Which apps are you having problems with? What have you tried?